# Discord Bot Maker Discord Bot constantly sits in offline mode

Tags: bots, discord

Right i am quite new to this so i need a bit of help. 
I did exactly as the deployment website on heroku (https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/lordshaxxxxxxxx/deploy/heroku-git). Having set the thing up i managed to get it deployed (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhqE8CtW1NWihdkqQGIZityJUidXkQ?e=TFX0dK) and yet my bot just sits there offline. I have to reopen it on the Bot Maker itself to get the application to get it working again.
Is there any way to properly make the bot independant from the Discord Bot Maker Application or nah ?

Answer (score 0):

Go check the video "How to host your not in heroku" from Tech with Tim. 
Make all the steps right and check the first comments for any updates. 
Remember... Heroku gives you only 550h per month which means around 23 days if you bot is running forever. You can add more by verifying your account through a credit card.